# ruby activerecord touch the record when we retrieve the record

Tags: ruby, activerecord

can we do a touch on the record while we do a select statement, so that there wont be multiple calls to the database

My question would be

Whenever I retrieve the user like this, I need to update "updated_at" field

```
User.find_by_username("a")
```

Otherwise there would be multiple calls.

First to retrieve the user

```
a = User.find_by_username("a")
```

then to update the "updated_at"

```
User.find_by_username("a").touch
```

Please suggest

Comment: 2 queries don't seem so bad. May be if you share the bigger problem e.g. fetching and updating 100s of records, you will get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do the `select` and `update` in one sql query with ActiveRecord(nor any ORM).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) there is an `after_find` Callback. So you should be able to use this in your model to touch itself:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_find { touch }
  ...
end
```

Note that this will most likely still trigger two sql-queries (so Зелёный's answer remains correct I think) but as a developer you don't have to type the extra call and are less likely to forget it.